# Open jQuery UI ComboBox on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery ComboBox input that when focused I want to automatically open up the autocomplete menu.

However, simply clearing the input and focusing it like this:

```
$('#select-id').val('').focus();
```

...doesn't work. If you manually focus an autocompleter input and then clear it, it does display the autocomplete menu.

Is there a way I can trigger the auto complete menu to open on focus? I also would want it to show the complete menu, so I'd want to clear the input text as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using the combobox that's an extension of the autocomplete widget:

```
$("your_selector").bind("focus", function () {
    this.value = '';
    $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
});
```

Should work fine.

**Working example** (normal autocomplete widget): http://jsfiddle.net/gEuTV/

Comment: Great Andrew.. it worked for me too... :) thanks for your valuable Answer..it's helpful to everyone...

Comment: Setting the minLength to 0 on the `autocomplete` is pretty important for this to work. It defaults to 1, as per http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength

Answer (score 0):

If you require this functionality for every instance of jqueryui combobox, not only for a specific selector, you can put this inside the $(widget("custom-combobox",{  statement
 (a good place for it is above or below _createShowAllButton)

```
_showAll: function() 
        var input = this.input, 
            wasOpen = false; 
        $(input)
            .focus(function() {
                wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
            });
             .click(function() {
                input.focus(); // this fires the call above.

                // Close if already visible
                if (wasOpen) {
                    return;
                }
                input.autocomplete("search", "");
            });
    },
```

This simply replicates the functionality of the show all button, triggering it on focus. This makes it unnecessary to create a separate bind for each statement and will work on every combobox you have.