# jQGrid + jQueryUI Autocomplete + combobox automatically open on focus

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple on this one.  After banging my head against the desk (literally) for a couple of days now, I submit myself to the mercy of the stack:

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete as a combobox in my jQGrid (I know!  I've already looked for the solution elsewhere to no avail!).  I would like the dropdown to open when I access the cell for editing through the onSelectRow event in jqGrid.  Basically, I want to do exactly what is discussed here:

[Open jQuery UI ComboBox on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990657/open-jquery-ui-combobox-on-focus)

and demo'd here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gEuTV/

The only difference is that I need it in jqGrid.  I've tried the code below which I (mistakenly) through would trigger the combobox to appear when the row is focused, but the combobox doesn't appear on focus of the row in the onSelect event. I have a sneaking suspicion that I'm just putting the following code in the wrong spot, but I've tried it everywhere I can think of:

```
$("#"+id+"_usr_validation","#list2").bind("focus", function () {
this.value = '';
$(this).autocomplete("search", '');
```

Here's my complete code including the grid:

```
$(function(){
    var lastsel;
     $("#list2").jqGrid({
            url: 'php_includes/uploadgrid.php',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:[
                    'User Value',
                    'Translated Value',
                    'User Validation,
                    ],
            colModel:[
                    {name:'usr_value',index:'usr_value', sortable:'true', width:60, align:"center", editable:false},
                    {name:'translated_value',index:'translated_value', sortable:'true', width:60, align:"center", editable:false},
                    {name:'usr_validation',index:'usr_validation', sortable:'true', width:60, align:"center", editable:true}
                    ],
            pager: '#pager2',
            rowNum: 1000,
            scroll: true,
            gridview: true,
            viewrecords: false,
            height: 'auto',
            hidegrid: false,
            autowidth: true,
            pgbuttons: false,
            pginput: false,
            forceFit: true,
            emptyrecords: "No record was loaded",
            onSelectRow: function(id){
                            if(id && id==lastsel){
                                    $("#list2").jqGrid('editRow',id,true,autocomp,'','','',selectNone);
                                    } else {
                            if(id && id!==lastsel){
                                    $("#list2").jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel);
                                    $("#list2").jqGrid('editRow',id,true,autocomp,'','','',selectNone);
                                    lastsel=id;
                                    }
                                }
                            },
            editurl: '/php_includes/jqGridCrud.php',
            });
            jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager2",{edit:false, search:false, del:false, add:false})

         function selectNone(){
                     $("#list2").jqGrid('resetSelection');
                    }
                    //this function de-selects all previously accessed rows

            function autocomp(id) {
                    var term2 = $("#list2").jqGrid('getCell',id,'usr_value');
                    $("#"+id+"_usr_validation","#list2")
                            .autocomplete({
                                    source: function(request, response) {
                                              $.ajax({
                                                    url: "/php_includes/Autocomplete.php",
                                                    dataType: "json",
                                                    data: {
                                                            term : request.term,
                                                            term2 : term2,
                                                            },
                                                    success: function(data) {
                                                            response(data);
                                                            }
                                                    });
                                            },
                                    minLength: 0,
                                    select: function(event, ui) {
                                            $("#list2").val(ui.item.id);
                                            },

                            });
             $("#"+id+"_usr_validation","#list2").bind("focus", function () {
                    this.value = '';
                    $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
              });

            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `'User Validation,` to `'User Validation'` and remove trailing commas in different places of your code (like from `editurl: '/php_includes/jqGridCrud.php',}` and close which are syntax errors in JavaScript, but ignored in many, but not all web browsers).

**UPDATED**: One more problem is that the focus on the editing field will be set **before** [oneditfunc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) will be called, so the "focus" event can not be triggered. As a workaround you can trigger "focus" event directly after the `.bind("focus", ...`.

See your modified demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Josh.htm).

Comment: Oleg-  First, many thanks for your prompt response.  Second, it's a bit of an honor for me to have my question answered by you after having read so many of your answers in the past.  Thanks for the tips on formatting - they are a big help.  Regarding your answer, the only issue I see with it is that after I select an item in the dropdown list, the list simply re-opens - which doesn't allow me to actually select anything.  I tried it on my development server (which has the saveRow functionality you commented out) - with the same result.  Any suggestions?

Comment: One edit to the above comment:  Oleg's code works perfectly if the user uses the keyboard to select the dropdown item (e.g., with the down arrows) and presses "enter".  It just doesn't work if the user uses the mouse to select the item.

Comment: @Josh: I answered only on your direct question about 'focus' problem and not examined your Autocomplete code. You cod had some other problems. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Josh1.htm) should work correctly with Autocomplete and my test data.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  You answered my question perfectly.  For some reason, when I select an item from the dropdown (in your demo), it just re-opens the combobox.  I assume that is just something wrong on my side though.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Josh: You are welcome! In which web browser you have the problem? Do you used [the first](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Josh.htm) of [the last demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Josh1.htm)?

Comment: Upon further reflection and review, I think the behavior I'm going for is better associated with a click() event than a focus() event so that a user can click on a row, the drop down appears automatically, select an item from the list, then the drop down disappears and the selected item remains in the cell.  Accordingly, with enormous help from your code, I revised your code to simply use a click event in the following section:

Comment: $("#"+id+"_usr_validation","#list2").click(function() {
                    this.value = '';
                    $(this).autocomplete("search", '');
                })
                           .click();
  }

Comment: Incidentally, the behavior wasn't a browser issue - but a rookie coder failing to understand his own question and the answers provided :).  Thanks again.

Comment: @Josh: You are welcome! I don't understand only the need to clear the value (`this.value = '';` or `$(this).val('');`) which you do. If the row will be saved (the user click "Enter") the old value in the grid will be discarded and reset with empty string. Is it really what you need? I think just using of `$(this).autocomplete("search", '');` is enough. The original value still be in the input field, but the full contexmenu will be displayed (independent on the value from the input field).

Comment: you are correct.  I didn't need this.value = ''; nor did I need $(this).val('').  Works perfectly now.  Thanks!